# How can I create a cronometer/timer notification on expo

Tags: react-native, timer, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

My Expo app has a timer, and I want to show in the notifications the elapsed time. How can I do this on android?

I've already searched a lot and haven't find an answer on how I would update the notification every time the timer updates.

Comment: Typical solution should be using OneSignal iOS Live Activity - https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/live-activities-sdk-methods

Comment: If you are only using local notifications you don’t need any third party framework.
Here you can find a guide (https://dev.to/neeleshrj/local-notifications-using-expo-25il)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.